# How come my website wrapper appears is totally different in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Hi im currently in the process of making my first website and I have nearly completed it except when i checked my website in firefox there was an issue with the wrapper as seen here 
http://prntscr.com/5bxbiy

this is what it looks like on google chrome:
http://prntscr.com/5bxbxp

Does anybody know what my problem is?

Here is my css

```
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1020px;
   width:98%;
   background: #fefbe8;
   border: 1px solid #878e63;
```

Let me know if i need to provide more information to help get an answer, thanks.

Comment: I suspect the resolution in chrome and firefox is not the same, did you have zoom turned off in both screenshoot you send us. Also it would be better to have the full page skeleton. Or even better can you provide a link to the website, so someone can inspect it with firebug and see what is happening.

Comment: that looks to me like a `float` clearing issue (the firefox screen has the body wrapper looking like its not filled) have a look into something called a "clearfix", similarly this could be an issue of a `div` not being closed correctly (ie. missing `</div>`) that chrome is being nice and closing for you, but firefox is flipping out about

Comment: Yeah I zoomed out on the chrome one to show you what it should like like altogether.

Comment: Yeah i was missing a /div thanks haxxton silly mistake on my part!